# Downloading files using Indy TIdHTTP

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I currently have a program that downloads a file from my VPS and extracts it. I want to make it download straight from the original website, but it doesn't want to work. I want to make it download this link:

https://bintray.com/oxidemod/builds/download_file?file_path=Oxide-Rust.zip

Instead of this:

http://41.185.91.51/RSM/Oxide-Rust.zip

Edit: Using this link:

https://dl.bintray.com/oxidemod/builds/Oxide-Rust.zip

Also doesnt work, even when using the SSL protocol.

I'm using RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo.

I found the following post, but I'm struggling to add it to my current project:

[Downloaded files using TIdHTTP INDY 10](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23286908/Downloaded-files-using-TIdHTTP-INDY-10.html)

Here is my current project code:

```
unit uOxideModInstaller;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, System.Zip;

type

  TDownload = class;

  Tfrmoxidemodinstaller = class(TForm)
    lbl1: TLabel;
    pb1: TProgressBar;
    btn1: TButton;
    btn2: TButton;
    lblstatus: TLabel;
    procedure btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TDownload = class(TThread)
  private
    httpclient: TIdHTTP;
    url: string;
    filename: string;
    maxprogressbar: integer;
    progressbarstatus: integer;
    procedure ExtractZip(ZipFile: string; ExtractPath: string);
    procedure idhttp1Work(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
      AWorkCount: Int64);
    procedure idhttp1WorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
      AWorkCountMax: Int64);
    procedure UpdateProgressBar;
    procedure SetMaxProgressBar;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: boolean; aurl, afilename: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  frmoxidemodinstaller: Tfrmoxidemodinstaller;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{ Thread }

constructor TDownload.Create(CreateSuspended: boolean; aurl, afilename: string);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  httpclient := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  httpclient.OnWorkBegin := idhttp1WorkBegin;
  httpclient.OnWork := idhttp1Work;
  url := aurl;
  filename := afilename;
end;

procedure TDownload.idhttp1Work(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  AWorkCount: Int64);
begin
  progressbarstatus := AWorkCount;
  Queue(UpdateProgressBar);

end;

procedure TDownload.idhttp1WorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  AWorkCountMax: Int64);
begin
  maxprogressbar := AWorkCountMax;
  Queue(SetMaxProgressBar);
end;

procedure TDownload.Execute;
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    httpclient.Get(url, Stream);
    Stream.SaveToFile(filename);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TDownload.UpdateProgressBar;
var
  ZipFile: string;
begin
  frmoxidemodinstaller.pb1.Position := progressbarstatus;
  frmoxidemodinstaller.lblstatus.Caption := 'Downloading...';

  if frmoxidemodinstaller.pb1.Position = frmoxidemodinstaller.pb1.Max then
  begin
    frmoxidemodinstaller.lblstatus.Caption := 'Done Downloading. Installing...';
    Sleep(2000);
    ExtractZip('oxide.zip', GetCurrentDir);
  end;
end;

procedure TDownload.SetMaxProgressBar;
begin
  frmoxidemodinstaller.pb1.Max := maxprogressbar;
end;

destructor TDownload.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(httpclient);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TDownload.ExtractZip(ZipFile, ExtractPath: string);
begin
  if TZipFile.IsValid(ZipFile) then
  begin
    TZipFile.ExtractZipFile(ZipFile, ExtractPath);
    frmoxidemodinstaller.lblstatus.Caption := 'Oxide Installed!';
    DeleteFile(ZipFile);
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('Error installing oxide!');
    frmoxidemodinstaller.lblstatus.Caption := 'Error Installing Oxide!';
  end;
end;

procedure Tfrmoxidemodinstaller.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DownloadThread: TDownload;
  link: string;
begin
  link := 'http://41.185.91.51/RSM/Oxide-Rust.zip';
  DownloadThread := TDownload.Create(true, link, 'oxide.zip');
  DownloadThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
  DownloadThread.Start;
end;

procedure Tfrmoxidemodinstaller.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

end.
```

Comment: [This link](https://bintray.com/oxidemod/builds/download_file?file_path=Oxide-Rust.zip) gets redirected to [This page](https://dl.bintray.com/oxidemod/builds/Oxide-Rust.zip) you need to call `httpclient.HandleRedirects := True;` at the `constructor` of the `TDownload` class, After `httpclient := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);` to make your `TIdHTTP` handle it, Regarding the other links it's just work fine. also `TIdHTTP` can handle https urls internally in the new Indy versions so you dont have to create `SSL`handler unless you have too.

Comment: It wont download. There's nothing going on. No output. No errors no nothing

Comment: When using debug mode i get this

First chance exception at $776BB802. Exception class EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary with message 'Could not load SSL library.'. Process pRSM.exe (4280)

Comment: You need to install the OpenSSL library from here [32-bit](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/openssl-1.0.2i-i386-win32.zip) / [64-bit](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/openssl-1.0.2i-x64_86-win64.zip)

Comment: @RepeatUntil your links point too older versions of the DLL. Better check the directory listing for the latest versions: https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Comment: How can I install them?

Comment: the DLL must reside in the same folder as your executable

Comment: I have done that yet i still get the same error

Comment: Are you using the x86 or x64 version of the binaries? Is your application 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Why simply don't use http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient platform aware If you are using Tokyo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This url:

https://bintray.com/oxidemod/builds/download_file?file_path=Oxide-Rust.zip

Returns an HTTP 302 redirect to this url:

https://dl.bintray.com/oxidemod/builds/Oxide-Rust.zip

Because of this, you need to handle HTTP redirections.  Set the `TIdHTTP.HandleRedirects` property to true (it is false by default).

If you are using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo or later, you can alternatively use Delphi's own [`System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient) instead.  It does not need any external SSL libraries, like `TIdHTTP` does.  Be sure to set the [`THTTPClient.HandleRedirects`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient.HandleRedirects) property to true.

Comment: After debugging I get an error saying could not load ssl library. I have tried downloading Openssl and adding the files to the project dir yet i still get the same error

Comment: Got it working after I got the latest OpenSSL http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign an IOHandler for SSL.

Include IdSSLOpenSSL in your uses clause and add the following after you create httpclient.

```
httpclient.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(httpclient);
```

Then just make sure your OpenSSL DLLs are in your path or in the same folder as the executable.

Comment: What you say is technically true. Yes, an SSLIOHandler does need to be assigned. However, modern Indy releases in the past few years have been able to do that assignment for you by default: [New HTTPS functionality for TIdHTTP](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/changelog/20141222.aspx)

Comment: After debugging I get an error saying could not load ssl library. I have tried downloading Openssl and adding the files to the project dir yet i still get the same error

Comment: Got it working after I got the latest OpenSSL http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/